# CodeIgniter - log error about sessions while using output cache

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, caching

I am using Phil Sturgeon's cache library -- http://getsparks.org/packages/cache/show.

This works nicely - the only thing is that now I notice that each time a cached page is loaded, I get this message in my log:

```
The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt.
```

My sessions are stored in the database.

Does anyone have any pointer on what I should look into to solve this problem?

Comment: Haven't looked at this library yet. But a common advice will be, open up the library, find the error message and do the reverse engineering and conclude the possible scenerios. Than eliminate one by one.

Comment: one of my issues is that a session is created every time someone loads a CodeIgniter page - i wonder if it is possible to override this

Comment: Is it *every* time a cached page is loaded?  And you're not caching calls to the session library itself are you?

Comment: every time - my sense is that the CodeIgniter sessions library gets called any and every time a page is loaded - very likely there's a conflict with a session in the DB, generating the error

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you to search trough your ide in the library for `"The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be a possible hacking attempt."`

usually IDE has a `ctrl+f` find option just search and you'll be able to understand what is causing this message, then if you didn't catched post the code snippet ;)

> NB : usually if you are using an encryption key for the session in
>   your config.php , and you change that it will throwns exactly the same
>   error, cause the old session has a different encryption key (the old
>   one you used)